# Mass changing IP addresses for DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I run CPanel and I need to change ALL the IPs for one of the nameservers. Can this be done via CPanel or am I going to need to run a bash script to change all my nameserver files manually and then restart named?

Comment: Again, nope, you run linux. I feel like I'm repeating myself. :)

Comment: I know that. But CPanel technically in a way is like AOL. It takes control and wants stuff done it's way ;)

Comment: Right...which is why you shouldn't be using it. You're just hampering your own ability to troubleshoot, configure, and understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in CPanel if you like to point and click a lot.  Your best option is to create a bash script to automate the process for you.

Comment: Can it be done in CPanel? I know the settings only are used for newly created zones. Never found the ability to replace IPs.